# Bash: Rename file with prefix as suffix

Tags: bash

I am trying to do something fairly simple and am a bit unfamiliar with how to accomplish this.

I have a set of files that were named: `x2_filename.png` and would like to transform the file into this format: `filename@2x.png`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `rename` utility with the appropriate regexes.

Assuming the transformation is:

```
nondigits digits underscore nondots dot anything
into
nondots atsign digits nondigits dot anything
```

the command would be:

```
$ prename -n 's/([^\d]*)(\d*)_([^.]*)\.(.*)$/$3\@$2$1.$4/' *
```

The last `*` expands it to apply to all files matched by that glob and the `-n` switch causes it to only simulate the rename operation so that you can verify it does what you want it to.

Comment: There are at least two `rename` commands. It would be useful to identify the one you're using as `prename`, the `perl` utility that's called `rename` on Debian-based distributions, as distinct from the `rename` on RedHat style distributions.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [`prename`](https://gist.github.com/javiermon/3939556) command (`perl` script), comes with `perl` package in Debian, you can do :

```
prename -n 's/(\D+)(\d+)_([^.]+)/$3\@$2$1/' *.png
```

**Example :**

```
$ ls -1
x1_filename.png
x2_filename.png
x3_filename.png
x4_filename.png

$ prename -n 's/(\D+)(\d+)_([^.]+)/$3\@$2$1/' *.png
x1_filename.png renamed as filename@1x.png
x2_filename.png renamed as filename@2x.png
x3_filename.png renamed as filename@3x.png
x4_filename.png renamed as filename@4x.png
```

`prename -n` is for `--dry-run`, if you are satisfied with the changes that will be made run it directly :

```
prename 's/(\D+)(\d+)_([^.]+)/$3\@$2$1/' *.png
```